# Saving throws stacking bonus

Tags: dnd-4e, saving-throw

I have multiple questions about stacking bonuses on the same roll which ends more than a condition.

1) Feat bonus + Item bonus, different conditions of the same roll: 
Focused Mind and Armor of Cleansing vs effects which provide both ongoing damage and dazed condition. What bonus do I get?

> FOCUSED MIND
>   Benefit: You gain a +4 feat bonus to saving throws
>   against dazing effects and stunning effects.
>
> ARMOR OF CLEANSING
>   Property: Add a +2 item bonus to your
>   saving throws against ongoing damage.

2) Item bonus + Item bonus, different conditions of the same roll:
Boots of Free Movement and Armor of Cleansing vs effects which provide both ongoing damage and slowed condition. What bonus do I get? May I use the Encounter Power on such an effect?

> BOOTS OF FREE MOVEMENT
>
> Property: Gain a +2 item bonus to saving throws
>   against effects that apply the slowed, immobilized, or restrained
>   condition.
>
> Power (Encounter): Minor Action. Make a saving throw
>   against a slow, immobilize, or restrain effect that a save can end.

3) Item bonus + Item bonus, keyword and condition:
Amulet of Physical Resolve vs effects with both Poison keyword and slowed condition. What bonus do I get?

> AMULET OF PHYSICAL RESOLVE
>
> Property: Gain a +2 item bonus to saving
>   throws against effects with the poison keyword and effects that render
>   you weakened, slowed, or immobilized.

Rules forbide to add same type bonuses to the same score, but since these are different conditions and/or keywords and the score is composed, what do we do?

PHB page 275:

> **Bonuses and Penalties**
>   There’s one important rule for bonuses: Don’t add together bonuses of the same type to the same roll or score. If you have two bonuses of the same type that apply to the same roll or score, use the higher bonus.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You've answered your own question.

PHB page 275:

> **Bonuses and Penalties**
>   There’s one important rule for bonuses: Don’t add together bonuses of the same type to the same roll or score. If you have two bonuses of the same type that apply to the same roll or score, use the higher bonus.

It doesn't matter where you get them from, bonuses of the same type never stack.

Answer (score 1):

#### Bonus stacking doesn't care where the bonus comes from or what conditions it met, only what type of bonus it is.

As you mentioned, bonuses of the same type do *not* stack.

1. If you are suffering from "dazed and 5 ongoing damage (save ends)" then the +4 feat bonus from Focused Mind and the +2 item bonus from Armor of Cleansing stack to give you a +6 bonus.
2. If you are suffering from "slowed and 5 ongoing damage (save ends)" then you can apply both Armor of Cleansing and Boots of Free Movement, but their bonuses are both item bonuses so they do *not* stack. The encounter power on the Boots of Free Movement doesn't care about any bonuses that you're getting to the saving throw; you have a slowing effect on you, so you can use the encounter power to make a save (with all applicable bonuses) against it.
3. If you are suffering from a "weakened (save ends)" effect with the poison keyword, then Amulet of Physical Resolve applies its item bonus to your saves against that effect. Amulet of Physical Resolve does *not* try to apply its bonus twice, and even if it did the fact that both bonuses are item bonuses mean they wouldn't stack.

To reiterate: Bonuses of the same type **do not stack**. It doesn't matter where the bonuses comes from or what conditions you met to get them, if they have the same type then they don't stack. Figure out every bonus for which the roll is eligible then figure out which ones stack.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a more detailed answer:

SCENARIO 1: Focused Mind gives a +4 *feat* bonus, and the Armor of Cleansing gives a +2 *item* bonus. If you have both available and are suffering from, say, "ongoing 5 damage and dazed, save ends both," then you will have a +6 bonus to your saving throw against that effect.

SCENARIO 2: Triggering the Armor's Power will allow you the bonus from the Boots. I am not entirely certain whether "ongoing 5 damage and slowed, save ends both" could be ended by the Armor's Power, however.

SCENARIO 3: You only gain the *item* bonus from the Amulet of Physical resolve once, no matter how many of its conditions the effect meets. (Even if it was untyped, a single source will never provide its bonus more than once; if the Amulet gave a "+2 bonus," it would still only give a +2 to saves vs "ongoing 5 poison damage, weakened, slowed, and immobilized, save ends all.") You can, however, gain other non-*item* bonuses to the same save, as in scenario 1.

Comment: Your phrasing on Scenario 2 is very confusing. The power is from the boots, not the armor. An "ongoing 5 damage and slowed, save ends both" effect is a valid trigger for the boots' power, and a successful save would end the entire effect. The Armor of Cleansing and Boots of Free Movement both provide a +2 item bonus to the saving throw, which does not stack, so it doesn't matter at all which you choose to apply towards it.